# I can't see suggested synonyms unless I'm logged out?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonyms

When I go to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) I don't see any suggested synonyms.

[image]

But when I log out, I can see several listed there

[image]

Is there any particular reason for it? I'd like to be able to see what synonyms have been suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is by design, we only show synonyms you have the permission to vote on. The fact there are a ton pending that you can not act on in any way was problematic in the past, people could not tell what they could vote on.

I am open to amending this, but need some ideas on how.

Comment: I have a mockup in [another answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2370/18612) you can take a look at if you want a suggestion.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense I guess. I would suggest at the very least a message indicating this though. I honestly had no idea *why* I couldn't see them. Just having something telling me there's a filtered list would be helpful.

Comment: If you wanted to go further, I would suggest a "votable" tab like in WarriorIng64's answer. It's nice to be able to see what synonyms are already suggested so I don't accidentally resuggest one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we could add onto the tag synonyms page with the following:

[image: Mockup of synonyms page]

*<sup>(Mockup based on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuAWC.png) provided by root45. Please excuse the quality.)</sup>*

This would add:

- **"Permission to vote" column**: This would allow showing all tag synonyms, along with whether the user could vote on them or not.
- **"Votable" filter**: As seen in the upper right, clicking this could organize the tag synonyms to show the ones the user can vote on first, still arranged by chronological order. Alternatively, it could simply hide the ones the user can't vote on altogether (similar to what currently happens, but makes it an option to be opted into).